# How to draw Custom lines on touch move in Cocos2D in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a puzzle game.

In this game I have to draw custom lines on touch began to touch end points. For this I searched a lot, but all tutorials or links only tell us that how can we use drawLine method for line drawing.

[Drawing line on touches moved in COCOS2D](http://iphoneobjectivec.blogspot.in/2011/01/drawing-line-on-touches-moved-in.html)  is one of them, but I want to draw custom lines over my background sprite. So any one can tell me that is there any method in cocos2d so that i could use my texture image for line drawing.

If this is possible then please refer me link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [CCRibbon](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.4/interface_c_c_ribbon.html) to draw a textured line

**Edit to expand**

I *thought* I'd looked into this previously :-) This code should be adaptable for your needs also [non CCRibbon method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749853/draw-a-line-sprite-between-two-points-made-by-sprites-in-cocos2d/8760462#8760462) (Though it won't be as smooth as multiple CCRibbon's)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but it is not useful for me as i want to draw line each time from touch began to touch end. So every lines should be disconnected.

Comment: That's not a problem - just create a new CCRibbon each time you have a touch began event and terminate it in your touch end?